# php header not working after applying jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

// script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".loginProzor").hide();
    $(".login").click(function(){
        $(".loginProzor").fadeToggle(300);
    });

    $("#prijavi").click(function(){
        if($("#user").val() == "" || $("#pass").val() == ""){
            $("#labelGreska").html("Unesite korisničke podatke");
        }
        else{
            $.post($("#forma").attr("action"), $("#forma :input").serialize(), 
            function(data){
                $("#labelGreska").html(data);
            });}

        $("#forma").submit(function(){
            return false;
        });

    });
});
```

// form

```
<form id="forma" action="login.php" method="post">
                            <label>Korisničko ime</label><br>
                            <input type="text" name="user" id="user"><br>
                            <label>Lozinka</label><br>
                            <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass"><br>
                            <input type="submit" value="Prijavi se" id="prijavi">   
                            <label id="labelGreska"></label>                        
                        </form>
```

//login.php

```
<?php

    include 'funkcije.php';
    include 'spojiBazu.php';

    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    if(!$user){
        $greske[] = 'Unesite korisničko ime';
    }
    $pass = md5($pass);
    $ucitaj = mysql_query("select * from login where username = '$user' and password = '$pass'");
    session_start();
    if(mysql_num_rows($ucitaj) === 0){
        echo 'Korisnički podaci nisu validni, molimo pokušajte ponovo.';
    }else{
        $korisnik = mysql_query("select username from login where username = '$user'");
        $podatak = mysql_result($korisnik, 0);

        $_SESSION['user'] = $podatak;
        header("Location: index.php");
    }


?>
```

Hello

I'm learning web development and I ran into a problem. I created simple login form. It evaluates some errors using jQuery and the rest of errors are evaluated using PHP. Everything works except Header command in PHP. When user succesfully logs in, header command should redirect to index.php so user can verify it is logged in, but in this case header tag don't work.
Before applying jQuery (all errors were handled by PHP) header command worked with no problems. Can you tell what's wrong here?

Comment: " but in this case header tag don't work." What exactly do you mean? Is there an error message? Is the screen blank? Are there unintended side effects?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql-injections, use prepared statements. Also show us the error if you want answers :) And don't use md5, it doesn't add any security at all.

Comment: You're doing the ajax call - the php header will redirect the ajax response... not the page that the user is currently sitting on. You will have to modify your javascript code in the client to change the location.

Comment: you are also missing `session_start()` before assigning the values in session variable

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: @MarcB is right, when returning ajax response , header will not work. for redirection you should use **window.location** in javascript in your ajax success function.

Comment: I have no errors, when user successfully logs in, it should be redirected to index.php, but it doesn't work. When I manually go to index.php or refresh page then I get notification about successful log in. Can you tell me how to modify javascript code so client change it's location. @dianuj I have session_start()

Comment: I think your `header("Location: index.php");` is in the wrong location (*no pun intented*). You're querying, setting a session variable, then telling it to go elsewhere.

Comment: @MarcB What happens if the ajax response is redirected? And what is redirecting ajax response? We still get some `data` as response, whatever it is?

Comment: you might get some data, but whether jquery will honor that data is another matter - since it was told by the server to go elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Details,

Since AJAX happens "behind the scenes" (so to speak) your redirect will just interrupt the response to your javascript handler. So PHP cannot redirect your browser now, jQuery can. So **use** jQuery to redirect the user.

You'll need to return the URL and have your callback kick the browser to a new location.

On this note, since you have to return data to the front end, you'll want to add a `status` or similar variable so that you can switch your front end behavior based on whether the call "failed" or not.

Exactly what Marc B pointed,

"*You're doing the ajax call - the php header will redirect the ajax response... not the page that the user is currently sitting on. You will have to modify your javascript code in the client to change the location.*"

A javascript redirect is as simple as `window.location.href = "http://mylocation";`.

## Solution to your problem,

JQUERY

// script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".loginProzor").hide();
    $(".login").click(function(){
        $(".loginProzor").fadeToggle(300);
    });

    $("#prijavi").click(function(){
        if($("#user").val() == "" || $("#pass").val() == ""){
            $("#labelGreska").html("Unesite korisničke podatke");
        }
        else{
            $.post($("#forma").attr("action"), $("#forma :input").serialize(), 
            function(data){
                if(data=="success"){
                                 window.location.href = "index.php";
                            } else{
                                 alert("login failed");
                            }
            });
                }
        $("#forma").submit(function(){
            return false;
        });

    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php

    include 'funkcije.php';
    include 'spojiBazu.php';

    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    if(!$user){
        $greske[] = 'Unesite korisničko ime';
    }
    $pass = md5($pass);
    $ucitaj = mysql_query("select * from login where username = '$user' and password = '$pass'");
    session_start();
    if(mysql_num_rows($ucitaj) === 0){
        echo 'failed';
            exit;
    }else{
        $korisnik = mysql_query("select username from login where username = '$user'");
        $podatak = mysql_result($korisnik, 0);

        $_SESSION['user'] = $podatak;
        echo "success";
    }


?>
```

Comment: I get error message (alert) when I input invalid data, but when I input valid data my page is still not redirected, I still have to reload page to get log in notification

Answer (score 0):

from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called.

You can try with a javascript redirection or remake your source code with the header at the begining

Answer (score 0):

header() will not work after output has been echoed to the screen.

Check funkcije.php and spojiBazu.php to see if any echo happening.  If they are you need to find a way to remove the echos from those to included files before you call header() in login.php.